# Given an F, R pair of SSR primers of 20 bp, which is the active portion of each

Tags: pcr

I'm a math & physics person with a general understanding of PCR. For my question, consider this F, R pair of SSR primers:
TTGTCCGTTTCTTATACAAT
TCTTTTTAGGCAGATGTTAG

It is my understanding that if the 1st sequence is annealed with chromatin DNA from our specimen that a PCR product of about 260 will form with instances of the 2nd in the sample, using Beckman Coulter hardware. Likewise, annealing the 2nd will produce products with instances of the 1st in the sample.

I also have been instructed that only a portion of each primer is involved in composing the PCR products. If true, how do I determine what it is? In addition, a citable reference would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.